# Converting a floating point number to string

Tags: matlab

I want to convert a floating point number to string.

```
f=0.0000
str=num2str(f,4);
```

This give me this-

```
str=
0
```

But I wanted to keep the result till 4 decimal points.I understand using `num2str(f,4)`  results in precision of maximum 4 significant digits after decimal.It is not equal to 4 but maximum and that is why I get this answer.I want to know is there any way to convert this number to string with exactly 4 significant digits after decimal point?

Comment: Maybe try `num2str(f,'%.4f')` to force the decimal points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) instead:

```
str = sprintf('%.4f', f)
```